# Two tier sign in with Devise (Amazon style)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication, devise

Let's imagine I have following scenario

1. User receives an email that there is a new item waiting for her
2. Clicks on a link and is able to either confirm or reject item (details skipped)
3. Can then access a list of all her items

The trick is that I would like to allow all this happen without user signing in but then limit access to other parts of the website (like sending an item to another user)

How I see it is that:

- when user clicks a link she is signed in but only on tier 1 - with access only to confirm/reject action and read only to index of items (that's when Devise session is created)
- when user wants to access other part of the website the sign in page is presented
- when user comes to the website just by typing in the url `http://example.com` and wants to access own account she is asked to sign in.
- after sign in session is "promoted" to tier  which allows full access
- after some time of inactivity session is downgraded to tier 1 for security reasons

My inspiration comes from how Amazon works - you can access in read-only most parts of the account but before performing any destructible actions you need to sign in.

Does anyone have any experience with such approach or can share some blog posts, etc?
I didn's find anything on SO and Google mostly returned things about two-factor auth which is not the case here.
I also understand that there are security concerns with links in email.

Comment: Turn on devise's token_authenticatable. When user logs in set session[:role_id] (ex: 1 for auth_key 2 for password). Write authorization rules by using current role of the user.

Comment: But to do that you would need to use the `after_token_authentication` Devise callback in the user model, and then set a session variable that the user model has no natural, direct access to. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @platforms you are right but if I want the password login to expire faster that the session I may save timestamp on user model. That would make sense

Comment: And as much as this answer is a good lead it doesn't really cover my question. The problem is not how to auth user but how to keep this state (gory implementation details welcome!)

Comment: Yeah, the thing about Devise tokens is that you only get one of them at a time per user. So if you use the other callbacks to reset the token, then the link in the original email you sent no longer works if they try to use it again later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented a very similar behavior few months ago. I don't have very interesting resources to show you but I can explain a bit how you could organize or think about the problem to solve.

**Description**

1. For the problem you state, it looks like once you have identified a user, you have two different states you can give him:

   - limited access (perform certain actions, read most of the resources, etc)
   - full access (allows them to do anything they would normally do).
2. Having stated that, what you need to do is figure out in which cases you will give a user each access state (for example):

   - signing in with email token -> limited access
   - password -> full access
   - authentication_token -> full access
   - omniauth -> full access

   After that, you will need to save this information in the user session. This should be done anytime the user is authenticated, as you will know what strategy was used to authenticate the user.
3. To know if a user can or cannot perform an action you will need two things, know what the user can do, and the current "access state". Depending on those you will decide wether the user is allowed or not to perform a certain action.

   Whenever a user can't perform an action and is logged in with limited access you should bring him to the flow for verifying his crendetials. This flow is pretty simple, almost like a sign in but just with the password. Once you verify his crendetials you can upgrade his authorization to a full access one.

**Implementation details**

1. I recommend you to create a Authorization model which will represent the "access states" that I mentioned. This model will have to be serialized in the session so you should be able to build it from a simple structure and serialize it again into that structure. The simplest the better (a boolean flag, an array or maybe a hash). For the case mentioned, it looks like a boolean would do the job.
2. Regarding implementation details, I recommend you implementing this with a Warden after_atuhentication callback.
3. You could implement this with CanCan by creating you own Ability that would be built with an Authorization instance and a User instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing authorization and authentication. Devise is an authentication solution, meaning it handles the "proof me you are who you say you are" part. Authorization is the "Ok, I know who you are, now let's see what can you do". Devise doesn't provide an authorization system beyond the simple "logged/not logged". If you need a more complex authorization system, use an authorization gem. CanCan is very popular.

Comment: Either you didn't really read my question or it is very poorly written. I'm asking for a HIGH LEVEL solution somewhere between CanCan and Devise (probably will use both of those later in development). My question is not - which gem to use, but a conceptual one.

Comment: You explained what you wanted and your question title is "with devise". I assumed you were confused because you were trying to implement it with just devise. If you already know about CanCan, what's the problem exactly? All of your requirements are easily implemented with it, aren't they?